# Karma is not finding my spec.ts file tests

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

I have the following `karma.config.js` that is based on [this](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html)

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    files: ['**/*spec.ts'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I can not understand why that the report says that there was execute 0 tests. I'm sure that I have some files in my src folder that has the `spec.ts` extension.

> Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.079 secs / 0 secs)

Any one has any idea what may be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802120/karma-is-not-finding-my-spec-ts-file-tests/51802577#51802577) answer I realise that I didn't the follwoing files in my project:

1. test.ts
2. polyfills.ts
3. angular.json

I haven't realize early because this is a project that is install on another project. This means that I never had the need of running this project as a stand alone application.

To solve this issue, what I did was:

1. Create a new angular project by running the command `ng new my-app`
2. Check for configuration files that did not exists on my project (comparing with this new project created)
3. Import this files to the same relative path that the files of the new project created has.
4. Run the project and check for new errors that could appear.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *sure* that you have spec.ts files in your path, this is the only difference I see between your karma.config and mine:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
```

Mine didn't have the `files:` at all before I looked at this question though, so you could also try just removing it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the path in src/test.ts. Here is my code.

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

Comment: I don't have this file file :S

Comment: You need to have this file. Otherwise it won't work. What is your angular version?

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11

Comment: In angular.json, 'test' config will contain 'main' options that should point to 'src/test.ts'. in your case?

Comment: I'm using the project to be install by other project. I don't know if because of that, there is any thing that can cause that my project missing this files

Comment: create a new Angular 6 project and try to cmpare it. You can merge only karma related files. it should fix the issues

Comment: I do what you had suggested and worked out. I put the missing files like test.ts, angular.json and other. What I suggest to you it that you change your awnser with this tips and I will accept that as it solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

That happens with my unit-tests , actually one of the unit tests I had

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
```

which I replaced with

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```